# Из статического массива в массив с использованием указателей (C++)

Tags: c++, массивы

Доброго времени суток. Есть код ниже, который нужно переделать с использованием указателей.
Т.е. я понимаю, что тут написано, но переделать под указатели - не в моих силах. Пытался сделать своими силами, но вышло совсем не правильно. Прошу помощи.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color F0");
    int first = 10, second = 10, summ, temp, i, array1[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array1[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << endl << array1[i];

    if (array1[0] > 0)
        summ = array1[0];
    else summ = -array1[0];

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (array1[i] >= 0)
            temp = array1[i];
        else
            temp = -array1[i];

        if (summ < temp)
            summ = temp;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Max element: " << summ;
    i = -1;

    do
    {
        i++;

        if (array1[i] > 0)
            first = i;
    }
    while ((array1[i] <= 0) && (i < 10));

    do
    {
        i++;

        if (array1[i] > 0)
            second = i;
    }
    while ((array1[i] <= 0) && (i < 10));

    if ((second == 10) || (first == 10))
        cout << "-----" << endl;
    else
    {
        summ = 0;

        for (i = first; i <= second; i++)
            summ = summ + array1[i];

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Sum: " << summ;
    }
}
```

Comment: std::vector использовать нельзя?

Comment: замените все 10ки на константу для начала

Comment: Извините, неправильно написал задание. Уже исправил. Нужно переделать данный код с использованием указателей. Уже голова кругом идет от этих массивов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем варианте по сути все, что нужно сделать - заменить

```
int first=10, second=10,summ,temp,i, array1[10];
```

на

```
int first=10, second=10,summ,temp,i, *array1 = new int[10];
```

и добавить перед последней фигурной скобкой

```
delete [] array1;
```

Как таковой, *динамическим массив* - т.е. массив, меняющий свой размер - у вас не нужен. Здесь просто использован массив в динамической памяти...

Comment: "у вас не нужен" - но ведь вопрос был о том, что нужен. Вероятно, нужно размер запросить у пользователя? И потом менять каким-то образом? о.О

Comment: Извините, неправильно написал задание. Уже исправил. Нужно переделать данный код с использованием указателей. Уже голова кругом идет от этих массивов.

Comment: А вот с указателями - самое то. Разве что, если очень хочется, можно еще позаменять `array1[i]` на `*(array1+i)`

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Не думал, что это будет так просто.  :)